# Is this the proper Session_start()

Tags: php, session, cookies, browser, session-cookies

Alright having a small issue with sessions. It seems that some browsers the sessions arent being placed, like my dad's mac book, but the thing is his Safari is only blocking cookies from third parties, even when i stated never block the session also wasnt started. Its only like this on a small number of examples; my brothers mac works fine. Anyway here is the code:

Login Page:

```
    if ($email==$dbusername&&md5($pass)==$dbpassword){
            $_SESSION['username']=$email;
            header( 'Location: http://www.website/start.php' ) ;
```

Start Page:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username']){
}
else{
die("<li style=\" color: black; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-left: 550px; margin-top: 300px; font-size: 24px; \" ><a  style=\"text-decoration: none;\" href=\"index.php\">Login or Register<a></li>  ");
```

anyway on my dads mac, and another pc i tested today i found that the session was never created. Any help? Also im new to stackoverflow, please dont bash me for this post, i mean from everything i have heard about stackoverflow, mainly it being useful for people like me, why would bashing even be allowed, if i am posting in the wrong section kindly tell me so and redirect me. Its professionlism. Thanks guys.

Comment: do you have `session_start()` also in the login page?

Comment: I would also use `if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {` to avoid potential problems (warnings).
`

Comment: Are you sure that these browsers accept cookies? use `header( 'Location: http://www.website/start.php?'.SID )` to keep the session alive when cookies are not accepted

Comment: Update: Yes i have session_start on login page sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Although you need to answer @haynar1658's question, if you are using `session_start()` on both pages, a potential problem could be your redirect:

```
header( 'Location: http://www.website/start.php' ) ;
```

(I am assuming that your mean `www.website.com` or something similar).

If your site is both available as `www.website.com` and `website.com`, the problem you describe would occur if you login on `website.com`. Then you will have a session open on `website.com` but **not** on `www.website.com` so after your redirect you will see your error message.

**Edit**: To have your session work across sub-domains, you can use something like:

```
$some_name = session_name("some_name");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.website.com');
session_start();
```

everywhere where you use `session_start();`.

An alternative would be to use something like an `.htaccess` file to always redirect to the `www` version.

Comment: @Mike Yeah You can set a session name and cookie parameters, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` should be on the page that saves to the session as well as on the page that retrieves data from the session.

I usually have `session_start()` at the top of a file that's included on all pages.